# Can I use t-test to compare my control and sample mean to confirm significant difference?

Tags: t-test, biostatistics, inference

My control is a sample without any drug treatment. My samples are treated with drugs. They were both randomly taken from a normal distribution.

The hypothesis is $\text{H}_0: \mu = \mu_0$ and $\text{H}_\text{a}: \mu \neq \mu_0$

The calculation would be $t = (X-\mu_0)/(S/\sqrt n)$ and then confirm whether or not the control and the sample mean are significantly different.

$\mu_0$ is based on the mean taken from the control, and X comes from sample mean

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers with examples that make sense and [here is one of them](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/independent-t.html). Just change smoker and nonsmokers to drug-eaters and drug-haters, replace the data and... yes, you have answered your question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors in your formulation.

You have given the formula for a one-sample t-test, but your problem is a two sample.

This leads to further errors (you're taking your hypothesized population mean from your control sample).

You should use a two sample test for a two sample problem.

When you say "they were both randomly taken from a normal distribution"... how do you know this? (Or is this a self-study problem?)